# Magento trying to autoload class unnecessarily

Tags: php, magento, autoload

I'm using a 3rd party php library to connect to Microsoft Dynamics CRM, which I've placed in the /lib folder of Magento.

I've created a controller for testing purposes, in which I'm including the files from the lib folder (which are being included, as changing the paths throws an error), but when I try and initiate the class defined in one of the included files, i get this warning:

```
Warning: include(DynamicsCRM2011\Connector.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory.
```

It shouldn't be trying to include anything, the class is already defined in a previously included file!

Any ideas how I can prevent this from happening? I'd have thought it would only try to autoload the file if the class is undefined surely?

Comment: Are you sure the library itself isn't including the files, making your includes redundant? That fact that you have already included it won't stop the other script doing so if it is using include rather than include_once.

Comment: It's all using require_once and include_once anyway, so no major issue there, however the stack trace suggests its trying to use Varien_Autoload() on the class I'm trying to initiate, which it shouldn't be, because it won't find it as it's not a Magento library, it's just a generic PHP one :(

Comment: If the autoloader is used, the class is not yet defined, therefore the autoloader tries to prevend a "class not found" error. So check your includes and wether you have no typo in your classname

Comment: Your warning indicates that this is an include and not an include_once. Figure out where that include is located.

Comment: Magento's autoloader uses include actually, you're right mpaepper. All of mine are include_once though.

The class is defined though, that's why I'm stumped! The files are definitely being included (echoing out a string and exiting inside the files works), and I've copied and pasted the class names to be sure!

Comment: put a die() in front of your class Connector{} declaration. If the program dies, you know your class is loaded. if the error is thrown, then some include is wrong and you class is not loaded. OR BETTER use xdebug and have a look where your program runs :)

Comment: Done that already - see my comment above yours - "The files are definitely being included (echoing out a string and exiting inside the files works), and I've copied and pasted the class names to be sure"